# Process has died

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just trying to launch a file using `roslaunch rtklib.launch` but it constantly says that process has died. I have spent a lot of time fixing this problem but I cannot. Also everything was working fine yesterday but when I try to launch it now, it does not work. The error is as follows

```
started roslaunch server http://malik:34688/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /rtkrcv/inpstr1_format
 * /rtkrcv/inpstr1_path
 * /rtkrcv/inpstr1_type
 * /rtkrcv/out_degform
 * /rtkrcv/out_outstat
 * /rtkrcv/out_solformat
 * /rtkrcv/out_timeform
 * /rtkrcv/out_timendec
 * /rtkrcv/out_timesys
 * /rtkrcv/outstr1_format
 * /rtkrcv/outstr1_path
 * /rtkrcv/outstr1_type
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_elmask
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_frequency
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_ionoopt
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_navsys
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_posmode
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_sateph
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_snrmask
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_soltype
 * /rtkrcv/pos1_tropopt

NODES
  /
    rtkrcv (rtkrcv/rtkrcv)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3881]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a204a6d4-e98d-11e2-85d2-081196dfce64
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3894]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rtkrcv-2]: started with pid [3906]
[rtkrcv-2] process has died [pid 3906, exit code -11, cmd /home/asfandyar/gnss-master/rtkrcv/bin/rtkrcv -m 3003 __name:=rtkrcv __log:=/home/asfandyar/.ros/log/a204a6d4-e98d-11e2-85d2-081196dfce64/rtkrcv-2.log].
log file: /home/asfandyar/.ros/log/a204a6d4-e98d-11e2-85d2-081196dfce64/rtkrcv-2*.log
```

I have already tried `netstat -ltpn` inorder to check there is no other ros program running. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67018/process-has-died/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-07-10**:
Can you please be more detailed about it. Forexample what is your output to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and all the other necessary details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am gonna answer it, just in case somebody encounters a similar error.
I got this error fixed. I checked my log files and I was able to detect the error. I was accessing data in my code which I had not initialized which lead to my program crashing.

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sagan61](https://answers.ros.org/users/4452/sagan61/) on 2014-04-03**:
Ohhh you nailed it!!! thanks!

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-11-26**:
hey ichecked my log file and its empty . what would be the error then?

**Comment by [Maximilian](https://answers.ros.org/users/25998/maximilian/) on 2016-02-19**:
Awesome! This error was driving me nuts! However it seems to only occur when launching the process with a launch file. Launching it "manually" prevented the error from happening...

**Comment by [TinTin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27493/tintin/) on 2016-07-15**:
Hi there, I just started using ubuntu for ros. I got access to the log folder, but I dont know what to do from there. There isn't a log file for rplidarNode-2*.log. Could you guys help me?

**Comment by [nesrine1211](https://answers.ros.org/users/25843/nesrine1211/) on 2016-12-23**:
Hi, i have the problem but i didn't understand what to add or remove from file.log?
here is my error:
[camera_tracker-25] process has died [pid 10473, exit code -11, cmd /home/nesrine/catkin_ws/src/dvo/dvo_ros/bin/camera_tracker camera/rgb/image_rect:=camera/rgb/image_color camera/depth_registered/i

**Comment by [yabdulra](https://answers.ros.org/users/52229/yabdulra/) on 2020-03-04**:
I'm having similar problem with my epuck robot, error message as : [epuck2_robot_0-1] process has died [pid 1039, exit code 1, cmd /home/yusuf/catkin_ws/src/epuck_driver/scripts/epuck2_driver.py __name:=epuck2_robot_0 __log:=/home/yusuf/.ros/log/4d087564-5e1d-11ea-a0cb-ec5c6878e588/epuck2_robot_0-1.log].
log file: /home/yusuf/.ros/log/4d087564-5e1d-11ea-a0cb-ec5c6878e588/epuck2_robot_0-1*.log
any help on what could possibly be the problem?

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2020-07-16**:
I got same Problem:
[mambo/mambo-1] process has died [pid 18827, exit code 1, cmd /home/rayane/catkin_ws/src/mambo_driver-master/src/mambo_driver_node.py __name:=mambo __log:=/home/rayane/.ros/log/b178b816-c762-11ea-9b53-48f17fbeed4e/mambo-mambo-1.log].
log file: /home/rayane/.ros/log/b178b816-c762-11ea-9b53-48f17fbeed4e/mambo-mambo-1*.log

did anyone find the answer??

**Comment by [salih](https://answers.ros.org/users/50477/salih/) on 2021-03-14**:
Awesome! I had same Problem

**Comment by [chrism](https://answers.ros.org/users/75240/chrism/) on 2021-06-23**:
Can anyone elaborate on what in the log files would indicate a data related error or even more generally what the log files should contain? I like to have the output parameter of the node in the launch file set to screen, when this is the case the log file is empty. When I set the output to "log" the log file contains no additional information that I can't already see on the screen